# Adding a library without ES6 or webpack

Tags: vuejs2

I am building a very small application that uses everything from CDNs, including Vue.js, so far everything has worked great, but I want to load another CDN now - [this one](https://github.com/egoist/element-in-view).

I'm used to that via ES6 (and usually Laravel's stuff takes care of that - do I have any way of including the CDN listed on that page and using including it in my code?

Simply including the CDN via `script` before everything else didn't work.

Comment: Why not npm install it and then import it into your vuejs project?

Comment: I was trying to go without having a node_modules or a package.json, but if there is no other way I would do that. Still can't figure out how to tie the included file to the inView variable that cries out `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can include the script tags in the `index.html` or any other html which you use to initialize your root vue component.

Comment: I do that, but it says that inView is not defined. How do I tie the inView variable to the included `<script src=''>`?